# Why can I write a generic catch statement in C# that does nothing?

Tags: c#, generics, try-catch, circuit-breaker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I catch a generic exception in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577760/why-cant-i-catch-a-generic-exception-in-c)

I have been reviewing and writing **[Circuit Breaker](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/05/the-circuit-breaker/)** code recently. The following method compiles, but the catch block is never entered. I have plenty of work-arounds, and this isn't the only way to get the right behavior (filtering exceptions), but I'm curious **why this compiles and doesn't work**!

```
public void AttemptCall<TException>(Action action) 
    where TException : Exception
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch(TException e)  // This block is never entered!
    {
         state.ActUponException(e);
         throw;
    }
}
```

---

Here is a test that should enter the catch block of the previous method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Throw_an_exception()
{
    circuitBreaker.AttemptCall<Exception>(() => throw new Exception());
    // test the circuit breaker's state
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. perhaps something strange is going on inside of state.ActUponException(e).

Comment: It should either not compile and disallow using a generic type as the catch filter OR compile and have the runtime exception caught and handled properly.  The fact that it compiles but then doesn't catch the exception is odd.

Comment: @Jimmy, try to run the code it doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @Anthony..this is duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577760/why-cant-i-catch-a-generic-exception-in-c

Comment: I did search before posting... there are so many choices how to word this problem, I can see how it happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a bug https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362422&wa=wsignin1.0