# What are some implementations of Exception filtering in the Circuit Breaker pattern?

Tags: c#, exception, circuit-breaker

The **Circuit Breaker pattern**, from the book [Release It!](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0978739213), protects a remote service from requests while it is failing (or recovering) and helps the client manage repeated remote service failure. I like [Davy Brion’s stateful circuit breaker](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/05/the-circuit-breaker/) and [Ayende’s lazy timeout fix](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/15/lying-as-a-valid-coding-pattern.aspx) is very clean.

However, I have not seen a lot of **implementations of filtering** which exceptions will cause an increase in the failure count of a circuit breaker.

---

*Don't worry about showing locking, unless your implementation is particularly dependent on clever locking. FYI, Phil Haack appears to have the [latest version of TimedLock](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/13/timedlockwithstacktracesstrikesback.aspx), used in Davy Brion's articles.*

Comment: Is this a poll or a question?

Comment: "What are **some** implementations..." means this should be a wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Filter by Predicate

A [predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) can provide extended criteria and filtering logic.

```
public void AttemptCall(Action action, Predicate<Exception> match)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if(match(e))
            state.ActUponException(e);

        throw;
    }
}
```

For example, you may want to increase the circuit breaker only on a `WebException` caused by a timeout.

```
circuitBreaker.AttemptCall(() => service.DoWork(), e =>
    {
        WebException local = e as WebException;
        if(local == null)
            return false;

        return local.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

## Filter which Types will increase the count

Your first thought may be to construct a generic method call with a generic `try... catch` block. However, the below will not work due to [a .NET bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362422), please see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577760) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029650) for more information.

```
public void AttemptCall<TException>(Action action)
    where TException : Exception
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch(TException e)
    {
         state.ActUponExcpetion(e);
         throw;
    }
}
```

You need to *catch all exceptions* and investigate the type.

```
public void AttemptCall<TException>(Action action)
    where TException : Exception
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch(TException e)
    {
         if(e is TException)
             state.ActUponExcpetion(e);

         throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Filter which Types will not increase the count

[Tim Ross wrote about this](http://timross.wordpress.com/2008/02/17/implementing-the-circuit-breaker-pattern-in-c-part-2/).

```
private readonly List<Exception> ignored = new List<Exception>();

public void Ignore<TException>() 
    where TException : Exception
{
    Type type = typeof(TException);
    if(ignored.Contains(type))
        return;

    ignored.Add(type);
}

public void AttemptCall(Action action)
{
     try
     {
         action();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         if(!ignore.Contains(e.GetType()))
             state.ActUponException(e);

         throw;
     }
}
```