# Exceptions not being caught

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, exception

We have following code:

```c#
try 
{
    // some code throwing MyException
}
catch (MyException ex)
{
    // [1]
    // no (re)throw here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is MyException)
    {
        // [2]
    }
}
```

If we run the code **without** a debugger attached, everything runs fine. However, if we **debug** the code, we don't get to point [1] but [2]. As far as I understand the language specification this should not be possible.

Even weirder, this code used to run fine even while debugging. The strange behavior started only a few days ago.

Comment: Are you sure that [2] is really executed? The VS debugger sometimes highlights the wrong line even if the right code was executed.

Comment: Is `MyException` part of other assembly? Remove the reference to it & add it again, build the project. See if that helps.

Comment: Clean the solution and rebuild it again.

Comment: PDBs are ok and in sync with the sources.

Comment: Depending on original sources, it may be related to this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577760/why-cant-i-catch-a-generic-exception-in-c

Comment: Also, check what did you install in the last few days?

Comment: @Guillaume 's guess is right: in the actual code the type of the exception is a type parameter. Sorry I didn't point it out in my example.

Comment: @Guillaume If you write an answer with your reference to the mentioned issue, I can mark it appropriately :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on original sources, it may be related to this issue : [Why can't I catch a generic exception in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577760/why-cant-i-catch-a-generic-exception-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have done a full rebuild and are using the correct pdb files. Also check that you don't have some conditionally compiled code changing things (i.e. code between `#if DEBUG` statements).